# OAuth2 implementation and user management Django

Tags: python, authentication, oauth-2.0, user-management

#### Overview

I've implemented successfully oauth2 in my Django project. After the user authorizes my app I receive an access token and, with it, I can access all of his information (username and email).
And so far everything is ok.

#### Problem 1

Now I'd like to use his username to let him log in without asking for his password. But here comes the problem. If **A** has registered as **some_name** on my app and **B** has registered on the authorization server as **some_name** then **B** can access **A**'s information on my app.

#### Problem 2

So, I thought I can use the email provided together with the username to double check the user identity. But here comes another problem. If **A** has registered on my app with **a_name** and **a_email** and the same **A** has registered on the authorization server as **a_name** and **b_email** then **A** won't be able to access my app using oauth2.

---

I know this is a theoretical problem and there is no code to review, so if there is another place where I should post this type of question, please let me know.